# The moderator action "Clear spam/offensive flags" is not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools

If I try to clear the spam/offensive flags on a post all I get is a blank screen and the flag remains on the post.

I get a redirect to a url like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/admin/posts/17315684/clear-offensive-spam-flags

but the page is blank.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We missed this during the changes to closing work.

Sorry.